# Cannot load MapService from ArcGIS Server in Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to put together a very basic sandbox app to load data from a public ArcGIS Server MapService using the Javascript 3.5 API.

However I keep getting the a 400 return status with the error "Output format not supported"

The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Simple Image Service</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.25/esri/css/esri.css" />
<style>
  html, body, #map { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
</style>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.25/"></script>
<script>
  var map;
  require([
    "esri/map", "esri/layers/ArcGISImageServiceLayer", 
    "esri/layers/ImageServiceParameters", "dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(
    Map, ArcGISImageServiceLayer, 
    ImageServiceParameters, parser
  ) {
    parser.parse();

    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "topo",
      center: [-79.40, 43.64],
      zoom: 12
    });

    var params = new ImageServiceParameters();
    params.noData = 0;
    var imageServiceLayer = new ArcGISImageServiceLayer("https://clientsServer/arcgis/rest/services/TEST/MyMapService/MapServer", {
      imageServiceParameters: params,
      opacity: 0.75
    });
    map.addLayer(imageServiceLayer);
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screen shot of the Network tab in the dev tools
[image]

I tried using the following but they also didn't display (I'm not sure what they mean, just found then in another post)

- https://clientsServer/arcgis/rest/services/TEST/MyMapService/MapServer/export
  https://clientsServer/arcgis/rest/services/TEST/MyMapService/MapServer/tile

Most simple sandbox app ever, and already scratching my head....  :o(

Any help greatefully recieved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create an [ArcGISImageServiceLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgisimageservicelayer-amd.html) layer based on a map service REST end point AND feeding `ImageServiceParameters`. The server then expects that this would be a map service with the [imagery support](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/image-service.htm), however, most likely yours is not one.

Most likely, you would need to use the [`ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html) instead.

Comment: Hi Alex,

Yup you were right. Changed code to as follows:

urlUtils.addProxyRule({
 urlPrefix: "gis.subsea7.com/arcgis/rest/services",
 proxyUrl: "http://localhost/ESRI-Proxy/proxy.ashx" });

ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://clientsServer/arcgis/rest/services/TEST/MyMapService/MapServer", {
          "opacity" : 0.5,
          "imageParameters" : imageParameters
        });

Used the ESRI proxy at : https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/tree/master/DotNet so clients server is not setup for CORS.

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries, glad it worked out well. I can recommend keeping the REST API help page handy as you will likely spend some time there https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/map-service.htm. Also, since you are exploring the ArcGIS Server REST API, I also suggest installing Postman and poking around submitting some requests and seeing what you can get back, super helpful app.